# magento - join group_price to product collection

Tags: magento, join

When I get the product collection with :

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
```

I get a group_price key but it's empty. (product have group_price)

```
 Array
 (
    [entity_id] => 1
    [entity_type_id] => 4
    [attribute_set_id] => 2
    [type_id] => simple
    [sku] => 00000
    ......
    [group_price] => Array
        (
        )

    ......
)
```

And if I load the product I can get the group_price data with :

```
$product_id = '1';
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$group_price = $product->getData('group_price');
```

I tried different query with join() or joinTable() or joinLeft() with table 'catalog_product_entity_group_price' but without success.

How to join group_price data to the collection with a join query ?

I would like to avoid iterating the collection to load each product and get the group_price.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the product in foreach loop and then get group price

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
foreach($collection as $product){
    $product->setId($product->getId());
    $group_price = $product->getData('group_price');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I extended product collection class and added this function

```
 public function addGroupPriceData()
{
    if ($this->getFlag('group_price_added')) {
        return $this;
    }

    $groupPrices = array();
    $productIds = array();
    foreach ($this->getItems() as $item) {
        $productIds[] = $item->getId();
        $groupPrices[$item->getId()] = array();
    }
    if (!$productIds) {
        return $this;
    }

    /** @var $attribute Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute */
    $attribute = $this->getAttribute('group_price');
    if ($attribute->isScopeGlobal()) {
        $websiteId = 0;
    } else if ($this->getStoreId()) {
        $websiteId = Mage::app()->getStore($this->getStoreId())->getWebsiteId();
    }

    $adapter = $this->getConnection();
    $columns = array(
        'price_id' => 'value_id',
        'website_id' => 'website_id',
        'all_groups' => 'all_groups',
        'cust_group' => 'customer_group_id',
        'price' => 'value',
        'product_id' => 'entity_id'
    );
    $select = $adapter->select()
        ->from($this->getTable('catalog/product_attribute_group_price'), $columns)
        ->where('entity_id IN(?)', $productIds);


    if ($websiteId == '0') {
        $select->where('website_id = ?', $websiteId);
    } else {
        $select->where('website_id IN(?)', array('0', $websiteId));
    }

    foreach ($adapter->fetchAll($select) as $row) {
        $groupPrices[$row['product_id']][] = array(
            'website_id' => $row['website_id'],
            'cust_group' => $row['all_groups'] ? Mage_Customer_Model_Group::CUST_GROUP_ALL : $row['cust_group'],
            'price' => $row['price'],
            'website_price' => $row['price'],

        );
    }

    /* @var $backend Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Groupprice */
    $backend = $attribute->getBackend();

    foreach ($this->getItems() as $item) {
        $data = $groupPrices[$item->getId()];
        if (!empty($data) && $websiteId) {
            $data = $backend->preparePriceData($data, $item->getTypeId(), $websiteId);
        }
        $item->setData('group_price', $data);
    }

    $this->setFlag('group_price_added', true);
    return $this;
}
```